# MySQL database update with JSON and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an HTML  form which I am populating and then sending the form data to a PHP page using JSON, at this stage I have checked the data sent on console log and it is indeed being sent to the PHP page, I am then sending the data to MySQL database utilising the foreach loop and here is where I am encountering the problem.

The last inputs in the array $_POST as $key => $entry in the HTML form  are the only ones being sent to the database, the rest of the data is not being sent, what I mean is if I have six pairs of $key=> $entry inputs, only the last pair of n $Key=>$entry inputs are being sent to the database, I have tried all sorts of things and nothing is working.

I think my problem is on the updating with the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry) {
    $sql = "UPDATE form SET Quantity='$entry' WHERE Pipesize='$key'";
    echo  "$key"." ". 'has input of'." ". "$entry","<br>";
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: 1) Have you output the value of `$_POST` to check it contains all the data you think it does? 2) You are wide open to SQL-injection attacks - look into [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: If you format your code right, you'd see that the query is outside of the foreach. It will only run once your foreach is done, so it only has the last values.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_query is after the loop so it will only excecute the last one. place the mysqli_query in your loop. And use prepared statments to prevent sql injections and Never use $_POST direct without a check people can easly manipulate your post request

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry) {
    $sql = "UPDATE form SET Quantity='$entry' WHERE Pipesize='$key'";
    echo  "$key"." ". 'has input of'." ". "$entry","<br>";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

example of prepared statements, didnt test it. if you whant to learn more about prepared statments look on w3schools

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE form SET Quantity = ? WHERE Pipesize = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $entry, $key);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry) {
    $stmt->execute();
    echo  "$key"." ". 'has input of'." ". "$entry","<br>";

    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $stmt->error;
    }
}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Good, also try to implement the second example and try to learn more about prepared statements and/or how to sanitize your variables

Comment: I have also applied the prepared statements and this saves times on coding sanitizing statements, thanks again for this.